# Best books and resources for converting from Delphi to .NET / WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, delphi

I'm thinking to begin an exploration of the .NET world.

I'm a Delphi programmer since Delphi 1.0.

So I'm looking for the best resources (links, books etc) about learning .NET from a Delphi background.

I'm looking especially for resources on the Forms and building GUI application in .NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only book dedicated for Delphi developers is [.NET 2.0 for Delphi Programmers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590593863), but it covers only .Net 2.0.

I think the best is learning .Net with C# language first, then you can decide the best way to convert your applications, because there are some differences between Delphi 32 and .net work, for exampale there's no TDataModule or TActionList which many of Delphi developers use them.

Answer (score 1):

The best for start to study C# language because this language was created for .NET platform,
you can start with this [book Andrew Troelsen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430225491)